# How to create dynamic button on dynamic slider

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to create dynamic button on dynamic slider? I am new in this technology..I have use slick slider  and i want button on that slick slider which is dynamic and i want to redirect next page on click event of that button.

Comment: Please provide more details about the issue you are facing. You need to narrow down your query to the exact issue so that we can help you.

Comment: I have used multiple slick slider..in which image are coming dynamically now i want to use button on that slider which name is "review "so that when ..when i click on that button it redirect me to next page where i can give review ...

Comment: There is a similar answer here- https://www.codersclan.net/ticket/696. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will work..
instead of using dynamic button i have give link to that world using innnerhtml..  Review    and it will allow me to redirect to the next page.